# Rails 3: Link_to :remote => true with JQuery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Question update:
I have figured out that importing JQuery (even without using it at all) is causing `:remote => true` to not work properly. I get the following error in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' (prototype.js:5653)

And when the link is clicked, it throws the same error again before redirecting.

Responder.erb.html

```
<ul>
    <% @choices.each_with_index do |choice, index| %>
        <li><%= link_to choice, { :action => "submit_response", :id => @id, :response => index }, :remote => true %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Example generated HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="/poller/submit_response/yni?response=0" data-remote="true">True</a></li>
        <li><a href="/poller/submit_response/yni?response=1" data-remote="true">False</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you check for javascript errors in your console (firebug, chrome console, etc.)? Is javascript turned on? It's gracefully degrading, which is a nice feature if you plan for it, but obviously not so nice when you're not expecting it.

Comment: I will check it out in Firebug and post the results.

Comment: If you're trying to run both jQuery and Prototype in the same app, the load order of the libraries matters, or you must use `noConflict`.

Comment: WattsInABox -- thanks for the great hint. I'm a newbie and didn't even know there was a console in Chrome. Dave -- if you'd formally answer this question, I'll select your as the best answer. Your suggestion fixed it. I just had to import Prototype first, then JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Dave never formally answered this question, the answer is:

"If you're trying to run both jQuery and Prototype in the same app, the load order of the libraries matters, or you must use noConflict."

– Dᴀᴠᴇ Nᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ